Converting WordPress "Redirection" plugin data to Next.js format
I am building a Next.js website with a headless WordPress back end. Historically I have always used the Redirection plugin for doing traditional WordPress redirects.
I can easily export the configured redirects as JSON, for example:
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "url": "^/old/(.+)",
            "match_url": "regex",
            "match_data": {
                "source": {
                    "flag_query": "exact",
                    "flag_case": true,
                    "flag_trailing": true,
                    "flag_regex": true
                }
            },
            "action_code": 301,
            "action_type": "url",
            "action_data": {
                "url": "/new/$1"
            },
            "match_type": "url",
            "title": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "regex": true,
            "group_id": 1,
            "position": 5,
            "last_access": "-",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "url": "/about/careers/",
            "match_url": "/about/careers",
            "match_data": {
                "source": {
                    "flag_query": "exact",
                    "flag_case": true,
                    "flag_trailing": true,
                    "flag_regex": false
                }
            },
            "action_code": 301,
            "action_type": "url",
            "action_data": {
                "url": "/careers/"
            },
            "match_type": "url",
            "title": "",
            "hits": 0,
            "regex": false,
            "group_id": 1,
            "position": 4,
            "last_access": "-",
            "enabled": true
        },
    ],
    "total": 5
}

I would like to convert this into fully working Next.js redirects.
I have in fact done this partially, for the 2 specific examples shown above, by making a custom function that fetches the redirect JSON and does some basic conversion:
const getRedirects = async (params) => {
  try {
    // Get list of redirects
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.WORDPRESS_URL}/wp-json/headless/v1/redirects?time=${Date.now()}`
    );

    // If the response is invalid, return an empty array
    if (!data || !data.items || !Array.isArray(data.items)) {
      return [];
    }

    // Convert the list of redirects into a format that Next.js expects
    const redirects = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      try {
        const redirection = data.items[i];

        // Get the redirect data
        const {
          url,
          action_data: { url: destination },
          action_code,
          regex,
          enabled,
        } = redirection;

        // If the redirect data is invalid or the redirect is not enabled, skip this redirect
        if (!url || !destination || typeof action_code !== 'number' || !enabled) {
          continue;
        }

        // Build the redirect object for Next.js
        const redirect = {
          source: regex ? url.replace('^/', '/').replace('(.+)', ':slug*') : url.replace(/\/$/, ''),
          destination: regex ? destination.replace('$1', ':slug*') : destination.replace(/\/$/, ''),
          permanent: action_code === 301 ? true : false,
        };

        // Add the redirect object to the list of redirects
        redirects.push(redirect);
      } catch (error) {}
    }

    return redirects;
  } catch (error) {
    return [];
  }
};

However this is not future proof in handling all possible varied formats in which redirect rules can be written, including various regex formats.
I am wondering if anybody has solved this already for all possible scenarios. I haven't been able to find much, but would love to know if anybody has an all-encompassing solution for converting these redirects to Next.js format.
Thanks for any help!
